# Asymptotic analysis of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{D}{2n+1}\right) \log\left(\frac{D}{|2n+1|}\right) \frac{1}{n+3/4}$

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

For large positive constant $D$, I want an asymptotic evaluation of the sum
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{D}{2n+1}\right) \log\left(\frac{D}{|2n+1|}\right)  \frac{1}{n+3/4}.$$

Note that the sum is convergent since for large $n$ since $\tan^{-1}(D/(2n+1)) \approx D/(2n+1)$ and therefore the term decays fastly. This question is motivated from a calculation of Feynman diagram in quantum field theory.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The OP is seeking an asymptotic expansion for "large" $D$, not "small" $D$.

Comment: While, $\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\arctan(1/x)\sim -\frac1x$ for large $x$, it is not so obvious to me  that the series of record is $O(D\log(D))$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hi Jack.  I've done some initial empirical analysis.  It appears that the series is closed to $O(\log^2(D))$.

Comment: @MarkViola: I agree, see my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We follow the analogous development in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735390/asymptotic-analysis-of-sum-n-infty-infty-left-tan-1-fracd2n1?rq=1).  Let $S(D)$ be given by

$$\begin{align}
S(D)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{|2n+1|}\right)}{n+3/4}\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{|2n+1|}\right)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+1/4}\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

---

We analyze the first series on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  We begin by writing

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}&=\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&+\sum_{2n+1> D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}
\end{align}\tag2$$

---

For the first series on the right-hand side of $(2)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}&=\log(D)\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&-\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(2n+1\right)}{n+3/4}\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

For the first series on the right-hand side of $(3)$ we find using the Euler-McLaurin Summation Formula that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}&=\frac\pi2 \sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac1{n+3/4}-\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {2n+1}{D}\right)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&=\frac\pi2\left(\log(D)+O(1)\right)-O(1)\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 \log(D)+O(1)\tag4
\end{align}$$

For the second series on the right-hand side of $(3)$ we find using the Euler-McLaurin Summation Formula that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4}&=\frac\pi2 \sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&-\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2n+1}{D}\right)\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4}\\\\
&=\frac\pi4 \log^2(D)+O\left(\frac{\log(D)}{D}\right)-O(1)\tag5
\end{align}$$

---

Using $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(3)$ reveals

$$\sum_{2n+1\le D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}=\frac\pi4 \log^2(D)+O(\log(D))$$

---

---

Next, we anlayze the second series on the right-hand side of $(2)$.  It is evident that

$$\left|\sum_{2n+1> D}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)\log\left(\frac {D}{2n+1}\right)}{n+3/4}\right|\le D^2\sum_{2n+1>D}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2(n+3/4)}=O(1)$$

---

---

Putting it all together, we find that for $D\to\infty$

$$S(D)=\frac{\pi}{2}\log^2(D)+O(\log(D))$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am sorry to have not mentioned that the subleading $\log D$ divergence is physically meaningful. To refine the analysis to the subleading term, we should only refine Eq.(4). I tried it myself but stuck on it. How can I do this?

Comment: You're welcome.  To evaluate the next term, use $$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac1{n+3/4}=\log(N) -\frac{\pi}{2}+\gamma+\log(8)+O\left(\frac1N\right)$$and$$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac1{n+1/4}=\log(N) +\frac{\pi}{2}+\gamma-\log(8)+O\left(\frac1N\right)$$

Comment: Wow... how did you know that formula! Thanks a lot. But how can I refine the $O(1)$ contribution from the arctan term next to it?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Thise expansions come from the digamma function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have still one more question as I mentioned:
How can I refine $\sum_{2n+1 \leq D} \arctan ((2n+1)/D)/(n+3/4)$ term?
After answering this question, for sure I will upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: You could expand the arctangent function in a Taylor series.  That double sum will be $O(1)$.

Comment: I know that term would be $O(1)$, but to refine the analysis, I have to know what this term is. (As in Eq.(3) this term will be eventually multiplied by $\log D$ and I want to know the subleading $O(\log D)$ divergence.)

Comment: Have you tried expanding the arctangent in its Taylor series?  That should give you a place to start.

Comment: I tried as follows:
We have $\arctan x = x -x^3/3 + \cdots$ and therefore
$\sum_{2n+1\leq D} \arctan\frac{2n+1}{D} \frac{1}{n+3/4} = \frac 1D \sum_{2n+1}{n+3/4} - \frac{1]{3D^3} \sum\frac{(2n+1)^3}{n+3/4} + \cdots$
However, since $(2n+1)/(n+3/4) = O(1)$ and we are summing $O(D)$ many terms, the first summation gives $O(1)$. Similarly, the second summation gives $O(1)$ and it also does for higher order terms. I want to know the precise value of $O(1)$ term, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Each term of the series contributes a $O(1)$ leading term.  To proceed try using $$\sum_{n=0}^N n^k=\frac{N^{k+1}}{k+1}+O(N^k)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Following your argument, I got the $O(1)$ term as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)(k+1)}  = \frac \pi 2-\log 2$
by partial fraction expansion and using the well-known series.

Comment: Pleased to hear that you were able to obtain the desired coefficient on $\log(D)$ and find the second term in the asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Let us break the series in a few pieces:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{D}\arctan\left(\frac{D}{2n+1}\right)\frac{\log D-\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4} =\sum_{n=0}^{D}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{2n+1}{D}\right)\right]\frac{\log D-\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4} $$
behaves like
$$ \frac{\pi}{4}\log^2(D)+O(\log D)+\frac{2}{D}\sum_{n=0}^{D}\log(2n+1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\log^2(D)+O(\log D) $$
while
$$ \sum_{n>D}\arctan\left(\frac{D}{2n+1}\right)\frac{\log D-\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4} $$
behaves like
$$ D\log D\sum_{n>D}\frac{1}{2n^2}-D\sum_{n>D}\frac{\log(2n)}{2n^2}=\frac{\log D}{2}-\frac{1+\log(2D)}{2}+o(\log D)=o(\log D) $$
so
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\arctan\left(\frac{D}{2n+1}\right)\frac{\log D-\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4} =\frac{\pi}{4}\log^2(D)+O(\log D).$$
The series on $n<0$ can be managed in a similar fashion. We exploited

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\log n+O(1),\qquad \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\log^2(n)+O(\log n), $$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k) = n\log n+O(\log n),\qquad \sum_{k\geq n}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$ \sum_{k\geq n}\frac{\log k}{k^2}=\frac{\log n}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: @Mark Viola: There is a $\frac{\pi}{2}\log^2(D)$ which comes from $\sum_{n\leq D}\frac{\log D}{n+3/4}$ and a $-\frac{\pi}{4}\log^2(D)$ which comes from $\sum_{n\leq D}-\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\log(2n+1)}{n+3/4}$.

Comment: No problem at all.